# javascript-multiple-input-textbox-validation

Tags: javascript

I have `n` number of textboxes on a form. After the user enters a value in a textbox, I need to check that it's not a duplicate of any of the other textboxes. For example:

```
Textbox[0] : 1
Textbox[1] : 2 
Textbox[2] : 3
Textbox[4] : 1
```

It should alert saying that '1' has been entered twice.

I tried the following:

```
function findDuplicates ( obj ) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('analog_idorder[]');
    var answers= new Array();

    for(var ii = 0; ii < inputs.length; ii++) {
        if(inputs[ii].type == 'text') {
            for(var jj = 0; jj < answers.length; jj++) {
                if(answers[jj] == inputs[ii].value)
                    alert('Duplicate Id_order number');
                return false;
            }
            answers.push(inputs[ii].value);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But only the first two textboxes validate.

Let me know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Have you made sure that the name, analog_idorder[], is actually the same for all textboxes? Try alert(inputs.length); on line 2, to see how many textboxes it found. Also, if you've, say, spelled 'text' wrong, as the type parameter, they would still show up as textboxes, but wouldn't meet your first criteria. try alert(ii) after the first 'if' as well.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119495/javascript-multiple-input-textbox-validation

Comment: Ugh, I guess the first 4 answers were too....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding brackets for the if statement in the nestled loop:

```
            for(var jj = 0; jj < answers.length; jj++){
                if(answers[jj] == inputs[ii].value){
                   alert('Duplicate Id_order number');
                   return false;
                }

            }
```

Else the loop will always return false at the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks Baversjo i Will try out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of all the looping you are doing by using a associative array to store the values you've seen:

```
var answers = document.getElementsByName("analog_iorder[]");
var seen = {};

function checkForDupes() {
  for (var i=0;i<answers.length;i++) { 
    if (seen[ answers[i].value ]) { 
      alert("Duplicate "); 
      return false;
    } 
    seen[ answers[i].value ] = true; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Text 1: <input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="chkValue('txt1');" /><br/>
Text 2: <input type="text" id="txt2" onblur="chkValue('txt2');" /><br/>
Text 3: <input type="text" id="txt3" onblur="chkValue('txt3');" /><br/>
Text 4: <input type="text" id="txt4" onblur="chkValue('txt4');" /><br/>
Text 5: <input type="text" id="txt5" onblur="chkValue('txt5');" /><br/>
Text 6: <input type="text" id="txt6" onblur="chkValue('txt6');" /><br/>
Text 7: <input type="text" id="txt7" onblur="chkValue('txt7');" /><br/>
Text 8: <input type="text" id="txt8" onblur="chkValue('txt8');" /><br/>
Text 9: <input type="text" id="txt9" onblur="chkValue('txt9');" /><br/>
Text 10: <input type="text" id="txt10" onblur="chkValue('txt10');" /><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var vals=new Object();

function chkValue(a)
{
    var t=document.getElementById(a);

    if(vals[t.value])
    {
        if(vals[t.value] != a)
        {
            alert("You have already entered ["+t.value+"]");
            t.value="";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        vals[t.value] = a;
    }
}

</script>
```